# How do I pass data from a json file into a html file in Angular 2?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have this files.

***wordCloud.ts***

```
export class HomePageComponent {
wordcloudData : Array<string>;
private searchField : string;
private wordsApi : string;
wordClouds: any[] = [];
errorMessage: string;
listId:any = 1;

@Input() data : any;
@Input() testProperty : any;
@Input() dataField : string;
@Input() apiUrl :  string;


constructor(public wordCloudListService: LexiconListService) {}

getWordCloudList() {
this.wordCloudListService.get('/assets/adhoc-search.json')
                .subscribe(
                    wordClouds => {
                        EmitterService.get(this.listId).emit(wordClouds);
                    },
                    error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
                );
                }



ngOnInit() {
    this.getWordCloudList();
    EmitterService.get(this.listId).subscribe((wordClouds:any) => {this.wordClouds});
```

}

}

***wordCloud.html***

```
<div class="center" style="margin:  0 auto; width:  30%; padding-top: 100px;">
    <cst-word-cloud [data]="{{wordClouds}}"></cst-word-cloud>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to load a json data and display the data into the wordCloud hmtl. I'm currently having difficulties doing this? Is there anything I'm doing wrong? How do I pass the value in the ***wordClouds*** array to display it?

Answer (score 1):

In your `ngOnInit()` you are not getting the data of `wordClouds` in `this.wordClouds`.. just do this.

```
     ngOnInit() {
             this.getWordCloudList();
             EmitterService.get(this.listId)
                  .subscribe((wordClouds:any) => {
                                                   this.wordClouds = wordClouds;
                                              });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Just to clarify, now that you have replaced `this.wordCloudListService.get('/assets/adhoc-search.json')` to `EmitterService.get(this.listId)`, how would it know where the json is loaded from?

Comment: I'm not saying to change in `getWordCloudList()`, Please notice that I'd changed in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no data being loaded into the function. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not emit the data. First of all is emitting a data is not the right approach. You should always emit the states like Boolean values or data which is used for a temporary basis. I would prefer not emitting the data, instead store first. Store it in some dataStore/ Class file. Make a class and store the data in it. After storing bind the template from that class getter method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will explore what you said :) Cheers!